# How to customize Foundation scss styles within Ember-cli project

Tags: ember.js, sass, zurb-foundation, ember-cli

I have an ember-cli project in which I have included the [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) css framework. I should mention that I am completely new to using SCSS so please bear with me!

My `app/styles/app.scss` file looks like:

```
@import 'vendor/foundation/scss/normalize';
@import 'vendor/foundation/scss/foundation';
```

Now I want to override some of the styles; my question is where and how do I do this? It does not make sense to alter the code in `bower_components/foundation` but I am not clear on how else to do it.

What is the correct way to do this?

Many thanks,

Michael

Comment: Have you had a look at the ember-cli-foundation ember addon. It will load the foundation css for you. Then you can add new styles to your app.scss file. https://github.com/kiwiupover/ember-cli-foundation  `npm install ember-cli-foundation --save-dev`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simply override colours and the like, you can assign values to the variables (they are explained in Foundation's docs) *before* importing the Foundation SCSS. I do that in this way:

**app.sass**

```
@import "_variables.scss";
@import "bower_components/foundation/scss/normalize";
@import "bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation";
```

**_variables.scss**

```
$table-bg: transparent;
$table-even-row-bg: transparent;
$table-border-style: none;
$table-head-font-color: inherit;
$table-row-font-color: inherit;
$table-head-padding: rem-calc( 5 );
$table-row-padding: rem-calc( 5 );
// etc
```

If you need more customisation than that you can of course define your own classes to override Foundation once that is imported. You can import its existing css (and your own) into your own definitions with the SASS mixins and import statements:

```
.full-row {
   @include grid-row(); // brings in a mixin
   // more styles
}

.option-panel {
  @include someclass; // brings in the styles defined for class someclass
  // etc
}
```

Comment: I think you deserve a medal for this.